# How to implement GLCM algorithm in python(opencv) for image feature extraction?

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-extraction, skin, glcm

I need to implement an algorithm in python or with use openCV.
An algorithm which helps in features extraction of an image.
Images which I'm going to use here is skin images.
Please guide me to build this code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @T A  I have applied Edge Detection and applied Image Filters like 2D convolution, Blurring, edge detection, sharpening. Used Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF (ORB) for feature extraction of an image and also find matching pattern between two images.

Comment: I meant implementation-wise for your GLCM algorithm. People will be more willing and able to help you if you provide some basic groundwork. This also shows that you already put in some effort in research and tried to solve this problem by yourself before posting here.

Answer (score 3):

Question seems to be broad:

1) You can use skimage library in python:

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
```

greycomatrix contains the glcm matrix and greycoprops gives you standard four features based on glcm. Here is a sample [usage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_glcm.html). If you want to calculate remaining Harlick Features, you can implement them or refer to this github repository [GLCM at GITHUB](https://github.com/luispedro/mahotas/blob/master/mahotas/features/texture.py)

Do note that implementing Maximum Correlation Coefficient is involved due to numerical stability issues.